# Retrofit2: How to make authorization token header dynamic?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, okhttp

I am creating an App that will allow users to Log in using Basic Auth.

I have a retrofit client that uses an **Interceptor** to get the token. However, it only works when you specify the email and password used as a string instead of based on the email and password the user inputs into the login form.

In the code i have i set the Credentials to email = "email@test.com" and password = "test" and the code works and the user is able to log in.

However i need the **AUTH** variable to be dynamic. All of the examples and questions i have seen have a solution that uses a static email and password.

**My Retrofit client is this**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://999.999.999:9999/api/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private static final String AUTH =
            Credentials.basic("email@test.com", "test");


    private RetrofitClient(){
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request original = chain.request();

                                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)
                                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }
                ).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;

    }



    public Api getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

.

**And how i call the client is this**

.

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .userLogin(email, password);


    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

            if(response.code() == 200){

                //save user
                //open profile

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {



                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Logging in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only thing you have to do more is to replace AUTH with some other data source that can be changed from any part of your code where you need

**Explained.** *intercept* method is called on each api request, so your credentials can be changed at any time

---

For example

*Some singleton credentials provider*

```
public class CredentialsProvider {

    //Some singleton stuff

    private Credentials credentials = Credentials.basic("email@test.com", "test"); //Some initial data

    public void setCredentials(Credentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials
    }

    public Credentials getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }
```

*Somewhere in code where you want to change credentials*

```
{
    CredentialsProvider.getInstance().setCredentials(someNewCredentials);
}
```

*Retrofit*

```
public class RetrofitClient {

   //Your code

   private CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
   // More code

   @Override
   public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
       Request original = chain.request();
       Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
           .addHeader("Authorization", credentialsProvider.getCredentials())
           .method(original.method(), original.body());

           Request request = requestBuilder.build();
           return chain.proceed(request);
       }
}
```